# Work around for Excel maximum characters for formula

Tags: excel

My maximum character in formula bar is reached, i was looking for a work around.
this is the formula i am using multiple times with different city names and divisions.

i have 4 divisions, roughtly 9 cities in each and data expanding 2000 cells.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ATLANTA",F3:F2002)),"SW",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BIRMINGHAM",F3:F2002)),"SW",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CHATTANOOGA",F3:F2002)),"SW",
```

that is just part of it, i can divide these up but figured there would be an easier way to search one column for multiple names and depending on what the name is apply the division in another cell,,, s sw ne nw

i am going to attach a picture to see it works but because of character limit ill have to divide up the sheet unless there is a work around.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to recreate the exact logic you are using (I don't know your states/cities) but maybe you could apply this workaround:

Sample data:

[image]

The formula in `A2`:

```
=CHOOSE(SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"BIRMINGHAM","ATLANTA","CUMBERLAND","BALTIMORE"},B2)))*ROW($1:$4)),"BH","ATL","CL","BM")
```

Obviously you can extent this the way you want to

Comment: thank you, i was able to use both suggestions a bit and get it to work how i needed it. i apologize for late response.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture into VBA if I were you. Hit Alt+F11 and insert the following. It should be pretty simple to follow, i increments through the rows, we are assigning the value of range F1 to the variable cellValue, and then checking if each city is in the string (inStr) cellValue. You'll have to copy and paste each If statement for each city you want.

```
Public Sub searchCities()
Dim cellValue As String

For i = 1 To 2000
    cellValue = Range("F" & i).Value
    If InStr(1, cellValue, "Birmingham", vbTextCompare) Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = "SW"
    End If
    If InStr(1, cellValue, "Mobile", vbTextCompare) Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = "SW"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```